# How can I create a dynamic price list that is dependent on the type of car that the user has using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a car service section that when a user clicks on he or she is directed to the price list page. My problem is the list should be dynamic and is different for users who have a SUV when compared to the users that have a Sedan. How can I Implement this using flutter?

Comment: I guess an `if` in the right place might help. Other than that, maybe you show us what you have so far and where exactly you are stuck, so we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the class of the page you are going to render where you will make a switch on the type, or whatever, of  the car and do you  logic.

In the class declare a property and require  it on the class  signature.. then when you push the page give  to that property a value.